# Admob Ad Freezes Half of the Screen

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xcode, admob

I'm using xcode and I have a tabbarcontroller with multiple views.

I just added admob and added the ads to each view (in - (void)viewDidLoad) using this code:

```
  AdViewController *myAdsVC = [[AdViewController alloc] init];
  [self.view addSubview: myAdsVC.view];
```

AdViewController is the admob view.

The problem is, when the ad shows up, half the screen can't be used. The app runs fine, but the middle of the screen can't click, scroll, or do anything. I can scroll above and below the space.

i've attached an image showing the space that is frozen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfcHw.png

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the frame of the myAdsVC to something like:

```
myAdsVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks, where would i put that code?

cause im getting "property 'frame' not found on object of type AdViewController"

Comment: Thank you for the edit!

It says "property 'adMobAd' not found on object of type 'AdViewController'"

this is what my "adviewcontroller" looks like: http://i.imgur.com/bJQlj.png

Comment: Ok, I was going off a version of AdViewController on the web. Look in AdViewController.h and you want to set the frame on the view you find in there.

Comment: here is a link to my adviewcontroller: http://i.imgur.com/bJQlj.png

this is all i have in Adviewcontroller.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


     // BannerExampleViewController.h
    
    // Import GADBannerView’s definition from the SDK
    #import "GADBannerView.h"
    
    @interface AdViewController : UIViewController {
          // Declare one as an instance variable
          GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    }

Comment: here is a link to my adviewcontroller: http://i.imgur.com/bJQlj.png  
  
this is all i have in Adviewcontroller.h  
  
  `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`  
  
  
     `// BannerExampleViewController.h`  
      
    `// Import GADBannerView’s definition from the SDK`  
    `#import "GADBannerView.h"`  
      
    `@interface AdViewController : UIViewController {`  
          `// Declare one as an instance variable`  
          `GADBannerView *bannerView_;`  
    `}`

Comment: so in that case: `myAdsVC.bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);`

Comment: When i put that into each view, i get "property 'bannerview_' isn't an object of type adviewcontroller"

but then i try putting it into adviewcontroller and i get "undeclared identifier 'myAdsVC'"

thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: So does your code look like this?  'AdViewController *myAdsVC = [[AdViewController alloc] init];  myAdsVC.bannerView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);  [self.view addSubview: myAdsVC.view];

Comment: damn, I'm being a dummy. Try: myAdsVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);

Comment: YES! That worked. Thank you so much :) You're the best. Ill purchase one of your apps out of appreciation ;)